# Unable to open a Video in Visual Studio using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

This is the code that I have used to open a video file in Visual Studio 2015 community. I am getting errors when I debug them. The open video screen shuts off immediately after it opens just in a fraction of a second.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>                                              
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
//#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include <iostream>                                                                 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
Mat frame;
 VideoCapture vid("D:\\Projects\\Visual Tries\\OpenCV_try\\OpenCV_try\\Dinner.avi");
if (!vid.isOpened())
    return -1;
int fps = (int)vid.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
namedWindow("Showing Film");
while (1)
{
    if (!vid.read(frame))
        break;
    imshow("Showing Film", frame);
    if (waitKey(1000 / fps) >= 0)
        break;
}
waitKey();
return 0;


}
```

It compiles perfectly but when I debug it.. It displays the following errors:

```
'OpenCV_try.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x2dc0 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The thread 0x514 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The thread 0x2184 has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[1616] OpenCV_try.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Can someone help me out Solving the error?

Comment: None of those were errors. Your file was not opened so the program returned -1 and exited.

Comment: Is this a valid path: ***"D:\\Projects\\Visual Tries\\OpenCV_try\\OpenCV_try\\Dinner.avi"***

Comment: Do you really have 2 OpenCV_try in the path?

Comment: does your program have access to the ooencb_ffmpeg dll file? for example but it in the working directory or your path variable.

Comment: can you try different video files from different codecs and/or upload your video file for us?

Comment: Thanks guys, The Actual problem was that my opencv_ffmpeg.dll file was not properly located in my path. So I had to add    C:\opencv\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg\ to my path. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are no errors. `exited with code -1` means it returned -1 somewhere. Take a look where that is: your programm indeed does return -1 on `if(!vid.read(frame))`.

Make a `system("pause");` before your `return 0` and read the output